# Docusign PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED when trying to log in

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm looking into various digital signature api's and I'm having trouble getting the Docusign api to authenticate.

I'm using the first code example from their Github repo: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client#usage

But when it gets to the line `LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();` It returns the following error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}
```

I've tried two different integrator keys in the admin section of the docusign demo area but received the error above both times.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Ben, we want to ensure that you're successful. Please post more of your software showing how you're calling the C# SDK. (Please occlude your integration key and other sensitive information.)

Comment: Are you doing User Consent or Admin consent?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ADmELHcPpbM?t=130

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for `oauthBasePath`?

Ensure you are using the one for developer sandbox.

---

[DocuSign REST API Docs :: Authentication :: Working With the Authentication Service](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html)

> Remember that the authentication service uses different host names for
> the production environment and the developer sandbox.
>
> **https://account-d.docusign.com**    Developer sandbox, also called Demo
>
> **https://account.docusign.com**  Production